# Java log4j2 logger levels aren't being followed

Tags: java, xml, logging, log4j2

So I'm trying to learn log4j2 and wrap my head around the loggers and their levels and parental propagation.

Currently my source hierarchy runs is:

```
├── main
│   ├── java
│   │   └── calculatorMain
│   │       ├── Main.java
│   │       ├── someClass2.java
│   │       └── someClass1.java
│   └── resources
│       ├── Excels
│       │   └── TestExcel.xlsx
│       ├── FXMLs
│       │   └── mainWindow.fxml
│       └── log4j2.xml
```

and my calculatorMain is:

```
Public class Main extends Application
{
    private static final String mainWindow = //FXML stuff
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        logger.debug("Main has started");
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
        try
        {
            //FXML stuff
            Parent root = //fxml stuff
            logger.info("Main scene loaded successfully");
            if (root != null)
            {
                //FXML stuff
            }
            else
                logger.error("Root was null");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.error("Error",e);
        }
    }
}
```

My log4j2.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="BrightnessCalculator packages">
    <!-- Logging Properties -->
    <Properties>
        <Property name="basePath">./logs</Property>
        <Property name="filePattern">${date:yyyy-MM-dd}</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>

        <!-- File Appenders -->
        <RollingFile name="mainLog" fileName="${basePath}/info-${filePattern}.log"
                     filePattern="${basePath}/app-info-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingFile>

        <!-- Console Appender -->
        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>

        <Root level="ERROR">
            <AppenderRef ref="console"/>
        </Root>

        <Logger name="calculatorMain" level="ERROR">
            <appenderRef ref="mainLog"/>
        </Logger>

        <Logger name="calculatorMain.Main" level="TRACE">
            <appenderRef ref="mainLog"/>
        </Logger>


    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The problem is that the root logger which outputs to the console is set to `level="ERROR"`. From my understanding of levels that means my root logger should only output error logs or lower. Then there's my `CalculatorMain` `Calculator.Main` loggers, the former should only log errors and lower whereas the latter should log traces and lower. So my understanding is that error logs and lower will be printed twice and anything above error logs should only get printed to the log once based on parent propagation. However that is not the case based with my log file outputting the following:

```
[DEBUG] 2018-08-17 16:37:28.239 [main] calculatorMain.Main - Main has started
[DEBUG] 2018-08-17 16:37:28.239 [main] calculatorMain.Main - Main has started
[INFO ] 2018-08-17 16:37:28.741 [JavaFX Application Thread] calculatorMain.Main - Main scene loaded successfully
[INFO ] 2018-08-17 16:37:28.741 [JavaFX Application Thread] calculatorMain.Main - Main scene loaded successfully
```

These above logs should've only printed once. I've been following [this](https://www.journaldev.com/7128#log4j2-levels) well thought out tutorial but I guess I must be misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're having is due to additivity being `true` by default. Your tutorial is misleading in that it says:

> By default log4j2 logging is additive. It means that all the parent
>   **loggers** will also be used when a specific logger is used.

In fact it does **not** mean that all parent **loggers** will be used, it means all of the **appenders** of parent loggers will be used. You should read the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html), particularly the section on additivity.

In the additivity section of the manual, there is an example with some explanation after it:

> Notice that the trace messages from com.foo.Bar appear twice. This is
>   because the appender associated with logger com.foo.Bar is first used,
>   which writes the first instance to the Console. Next, the parent of
>   com.foo.Bar, which in this case is the root logger, is referenced. The
>   event is then passed to its **appender**, which also writes to the
>   Console, resulting in the second instance. This is known as
>   additivity.

With additivity set to `true` (as it is by default) any event accepted by a child logger is passed to the appenders of all parent loggers.

Comment: Very useful answer, my only plight it that if an event is passed to its parent why is the level of the parent ignored? Is it because like you said, all appenders by parents will be used? If that’s the case why is additivity set to true by default if it creates undesirable affects?

Comment: Yes, all appenders of parent loggers are used. The effect is not always undesirable - consider the situation where you have a main log file where you want all logs to be written. Consider that you're testing a new class and that you want to see all DEBUG logs from this new code and have them written to console (or perhaps a separate log). You might leave additivity set to true so that you can easily see the isolated logs and still see them in the broader context of your whole application since the events from the child will go the appenders of the parent and be written to the main log as well.