# Avoid Log4j2 write in parent loggers

Tags: logging, log4j2

In my project, I have some packages like:

```
com.project.my
```

I have defined several loggers for each kind of package, like:

```
<Logger name="com.project.my" additivity="true" level="warn">
   <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</Logger>

<Logger name="com.project" additivity="true" level="warn">
   <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
</Logger>
```

And more...

The problem is that when I write a log using the `com.project.my` logger, the output is written into the `com.project.my` rolling file log **AND** into the `com.project` file log.

I just wanted the output would be written into `com.project.my` file log only. How could I solve that?

Comment: Set `additivity="false"` for logger `com.project.my`.

Comment: Yes, thanks! It solves the problem. @D.B. , you can post the solution and I will set it as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `additivity="false"` for logger `com.project.my`. For details about additivity you can refer to the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Additivity). You may also find [another answer I wrote regarding additivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51905527/3284624) to be helpeful. There is also some information about it on the [architecture page of the manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html) as well.